# Tricky integrable combination for ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Please help me to find second integrable combination for the ODE system:

$$\frac{dx}{y-x}=\frac{dy}{x+y+z}=\frac{dz}{x-y}$$

First integrable combination is clear : $x+z = C_1$. But can not find second.
I already solved a lot of problems of this kind and I thought I am good with them, but unfortunately I can not tackle this one. The answer is $(x+y+z)(y-3x-z)=C_2$, but I am not interested in the answer, but in approach to solution for this instance.

Thanks a lot for your hints and answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{dx+dy+dz}{x+y+z}=\frac{dy-3dx-dz}{-y+3x+z}$$
$$\log(x+y+z) = - \log(y-3x-z) +\log C_2$$
$$(x+y+z)(y-3x-z)=C_2$$

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different approach than direct integration, but also thought it was worth a thought.
$$\frac{dy}{x+z+y} = \frac{dz}{x-y} = \frac{dz}{x+z-z-y}$$
Making the substitutions  $x+z = C$,
$$\frac{dy}{y+C} = \frac{dz}{C-z-y}$$
$$dy(C-z-y) = dz(y+C) \implies -y(dy+dz) + C(dy-dz) = zdy $$
$$-y(1+\frac{dz}{dy}) + C(1- \frac{dz}{dy}) = z $$
$$\frac{dz}{dy} + \frac1{C+y}z = \frac {C-y}{C+y} $$
This is a first order linear ODE in $z $